# Why Sometimes JS file need to add on top only?

Tags: javascript

As a standard practice we add a JS files at the end of HTML page, but sometimes you get some error and if we add JS file on top we get rid from the error and gets expected output.

Similarly if we add some JS file on top it gives error but same if same file we add at the bottom it will gives expected output instead of error.

Can anyone please help me with the logic behind that.

Comment: Have you an example?

Comment: Most times, when a certain JS file works when added at the bottom but not at the top, it's because it tries to access DOM elements (e.g. `document.getElementById`) without waiting for the element to exist. This can be fixed by moving the script to the end, or simply wrapping the JS with `addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { /* ... */ });`

Comment: The error log tells you exactly the reason of failure, so what is the question? That is the nature of one thing trying to run before another is ready

Answer (score 1):

it has to do with the way the DOM is loaded.

the browser goes from top to bottom, if it finds a script, it will download it from the source and execute it. this blocks the rest of the queue which means while the browser is executing this script, it will not continue to render the page.

if the script in question isn't waiting for the document to have successfully finished loading, any call to DOM nodes will result in failure, since at the time of execution, they don't yet exist.

if you instead load the script at the end, the DOM nodes will exist at the time of execution. any errors that result in this case are caused by the script itself and need to be debugged.

in general, it's advised to wait for the DOM content to have finished loading, for this you can use the load event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

Comment: The same dependency issue can be purely in Javascript too, it doesn't have to be DOM interaction. If "early" javascript is trying to use some part of the javascript that is loaded "late" then it will also error

Comment: In most cases, the event you want to attach your code to is not `load`, but `DOMContentLoaded`, which happens earlier.